# Dynamic list of valid values in JSON Schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

Given the following JSON, how can I use JSON Schema to validate that each string in `nodes[].targets` matches the name of a listed node?

```
{
    "nodes": [
        {"name": "app_server"},
        {"name": "web_server1"}
        {"name": "web_server2"}
        {
            "name": "load_balancer",
            "targets": ["web_server1", "web_server2"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON schema does not support such validation criteria.

You either need to define custom keywords if the validator supports them (e.g. in [Ajv](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv)) or validate outside of schema.

Disclaimer: I have created Ajv.